How can I install pygame on Sublime Text 3 in python to work a project?
I can't install on the console
I expected to see pygame installed.
I followed everything as my book said but it doesn’t work.
This project is very useful so I must finish it till next month .
I also want to work on other projects so I must finish this first.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
